# App does not connect to database after deploying

Tags: heroku, jhipster

I built an app using JHipster, which works fine locally. Then i deployed the app to heroku using the command `JHipster Heroku`. The app stops startup with following log entry:

```
 ***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
 ***************************

 Description:

 Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

 Property: driverclassname
 Value: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
 Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

 Action:

 Update your application's configuration
```

Obviously the app does not connect to the database, but how can i fix that?

Comment: What version of JHipster?

Comment: JHipster Version 5.3.4